# Save cakephp 2.0 associations

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to save associated data in Cakephp 2.0, in the database I have two tables, table entities (id, main_name) and adresses(id, entity_id, city)

In the Entities model I made the association:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Address' => array(
        'className'     => 'Address',
        'foreignKey'    => 'entity_id'
     )
);
```

In the AdressesController I saved with the following data:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Entity->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Entity successfully registered!');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));

        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(Oops, we could not register this entity! 
            Make sure it already exists.');
        }
    }
}
```

And in the view, my form looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input(
        'Entity.main_name',
         array(
             'type'  => 'text',
             'class' => 'form-control',
             'label' => false
         )
    );
?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input(
        'Address.city',
        array(
             'type'  => 'text',
             'class' => 'form-control',
             'label' => false
        )
    );
?>
```

The data of the entity normally saved in the database, but does not relate the entity_id and does not save the city in the adresses table, do I have to do anything else in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of solving your problem. Like described in [CakeBook: Saving your data](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) you can use [saveAssociated()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) or [Save each Model step by step.](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)

## Saving using saveAssociated()

In your `Controller/EntitiesController.php`:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Entity->create();
        // Use saveAssociated() instead of save() here
        if ($this->Entity->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The entity has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The entity could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $addresses = $this->Entity->Address->find('all');
    $this->set($addresses);
}
```

In your `View/Entities/add.ctp`:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('main_name', array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'label' => false
    ));
    // Make sure you use Address.0.city
    echo $this->Form->input('Address.0.city', array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => false
    ));
?>
```

Since you use a hasMany Association a Entity can have several Addresses. For this reason you have to set the `0` in `Address.0.city`. This will result in a data array like this:

```
array(
    'Entity' => array(
        'main_name' => 'Fancy Name'
    ),
    'Address' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'city' => 'Cool City'
        )
    )
)
```

## Saving Models step by step

Another approach would be to save the Entity and then save the Address with the entity_id like described in [CakeBook](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto):

In your `Controller/EntitiesController.php`:

```
public function add() {
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        // save Entity
        $entity = $this->Entity->save($this->request->data);

        if (!empty($entity)) {
            // Set the EntityId to the data array and save the Address with the EntityId
            $this->request->data['Address']['entity_id'] = $this->Entity->id;
            $this->Entity->Address->save($this->request->data);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case your `View/Entities/add.ctp` Address form would look like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Address.city', array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'label' => false
));
```

Best, variables